# How to detect whether an expectation failed in Jasmine/Protractor

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing

I am trying to test a page that, as soon the page is finished loading completely, does a server-side RSA keypair generation, which takes between 5 - 20 seconds with my current set up. The user is not allowed to do anything until the browser has received the keypair.

I have been using  browser.sleep(), but waiting 20 seconds if the keypair was generated in 5 is annoying. I tried to use Protractor's evaluate() method as a while loop condition, but realized evaluate() returns an ElementFinder rather than the argument's value. Is there a method that allows Jasmine/Protractor to compute a boolean value in the same fashion Jasmine evaluates toBe/toEqual/etc?

In short,

```
expect(controller.evaluate('data.step1.done')).toBe(true);
```

computes a boolean value, equivalent to the value of evaluate()'s argument in Angular's scope, that it compares against "true". Is there a way to use that computed value or compute it myself?

Comment: How is the waiting implemented on the browser-side? Is there any indicator for an end-user?

Comment: @alecxe The rest of the page's content is blurred using ng-class="{blurred: !data.step1.done}". as well as a few elements using ng-show with the same Angular variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea here is to use [`browser.wait()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) to wait for the blurred content to disappear:

```
browser.driver.wait(function() {
    return !browser.driver.isElementPresent(by.css(".blurred"));
}, 20000)
.then(
  function() {
    // success code
  },
  function() {
    // fail code
  }
);
```

In this case it would wait **up to** 20 seconds. It would stop waiting right after the blurred content disappears.

Comment: If it times out, it displays the amount of time it waited in ms, usually 20 - 50 ms more than the timeout amount. When it doesn't time out, is there a way to save the amount of time it had been executing the function before it evaluated to true?

Comment: @TahsisClaus please confirm that this option is working for you. About saving the wait time - very interesting question - could you please make a separate SO question so that others could help or find the solution to a similar problem? Thanks!